# N2 or Composite for simple site

Tags: content-management-system, c1-cms, n2

Would N2 or Composite be a more suitable CMS to use to manage a small business website?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

N2 CMS is more of a platform for building a CMS rather than a fully featured CMS in it's own right. There is though, an example implementation to get you started.  I would think that that [Composite C1](http://www.composite.net/) or [Orchard](http://www.orchardproject.net/) is likely to give you a quicker start at building a small business website if you're starting from scratch. However I think N2 be of use if you ever need to build CMS function into an existing site (but this would be quite difficult with the other two I've mentioned).

Edit:
C1 and Orchard also seem to be under more active development than N2 which doesn't appear to have had any new releases since early 2011.

You can install C1 and Orchard pretty easily from Microsoft's [Web Platform Installer](http://www.microsoft.com/web/downloads/platform.aspx). With C1, choose the [Omnicorp demo site](http://docs.composite.net/Getting-started/Starter-sites/OmniCorpWebsite) to see a sample deployment with a few pages already created as this will be the quickest way to evaluate it. Installing from the [WPI](http://www.microsoft.com/web/downloads/platform.aspx) is probably a faster approach than installing it from source for the purposes of evaluation.

Comment: N2 is more actively developed than ever (https://github.com/n2cms/n2cms/graphs/commit-activity). Source code hosting moved from Codeplex to Github.

Comment: @DejanMilicic But no new version of n2cms has actually been released since July 2011. Compare this to the others, where major new functionality has been added continuously since that time. Commits mean don't mean much if they don't ever get released (and therefore supported by others).

Comment: Latest version of N2 is 2.4.11.1 released on January 17th 2013. At the bottom of the page you have full history of previous versions. http://nuget.org/packages/N2CMS/

Comment: Yes, but the only official "stable" release and also the default download if you follow the main download link is the one I mentioned. My point is if you just do to their website and download the advertised version, that version is from 2011. Any newer versions are presumably not supported or are not stable or they'd obviously have linked to them instead.

Comment: I had to make the same choice myself about 3 months back.  :)  
I settled with C1 - it is amazing.  So impressed with it's architecture and the ability for me to easily integrate my custom functionality, or replace their implementation via the provider pattern they implement.  I would HIGHLY recommend working through their training material before you start working with it.  There are some gems of functionality you should be aware that may make your life far easier: http://docs.composite.net/Getting-started/Training
The training page includes links to their docs in a nice order.